# WinSCP + Wine + MacOSX open MacOS editor possible?

Tags: macos, winscp, wine

WinSCP is the best SSH client I've found. I can use it in MacOS through Wine to edit and code in remote files. However, I haven't been able to edit files opened in WinSCP with an external MacOS editor app (I have to install a windows editor throught Wine, and that works).

Is this possible? How can I achieve it?